# How to convert operators into Matrices?

Tags: matrix, julia, diagonal

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian using the `Quantumoptics.jl` package. But every time I try to do that it gives me an error saying `Methoderror: no method matching eigen(::Operator{FockBasis{Int64}, FockBasis{Int64}, SparseArrays.SparseMatrixCSC{ComplexF64, Int64}})`

```
a = destroy(cavity);
at = create(cavity);

beta= 0.1;

H= beta * at *a
e = eigen(H);
```

I was expecting an array that gives me the eigenvalues of `H`. I also tried to `H = Matrix(H)`, but no help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide a minimal working example that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Julia, you can inspect types using `typeof`, e.g.,

```
> typeof(H)
Operator{FockBasis{Int64}, FockBasis{Int64}, SparseArrays.SparseMatrixCSC{ComplexF64, Int64}}
```

If you want to know more about `Operator`s, you can type `?Operator` into the REPL to get a quick documentation, consult the package's [online documentation](https://docs.qojulia.org/quantumobjects/operators/#operators_concrete) for more details, or use `dump(H)` to see the fields of this structure.

Therefore, to get the `Operator`'s coefficients, you can use `H.data`. To retrieve them as a (dense) `Matrix`, you can use `dense(H).data`. Though, if you are interested in the eigen values, I would suggest that you directly use `eigenstates(H)`, which is the [implementation from the QuantumOptics-package](https://github.com/qojulia/QuantumOptics.jl/blob/7237d9ece39509020b82172c2ecdfd770d9cbc4c/src/spectralanalysis.jl#L5-L22) that can directly process `Operator`s and also takes care of the bases, i.e.,

```
function eigenstates(op::DenseOpType, n::Int=length(basis(op)); warning=true)
   b = basis(op)
   if ishermitian(op)
       D, V = eigen(Hermitian(op.data), 1:n)
       states = [Ket(b, V[:, k]) for k=1:length(D)]
       return D, states
   # ...
   end
 end
```